# How to exclude empty objects from Jackson ObjectMapper?

Tags: java, json, serialization, jackson

Basically I do not want any empty JSON arrays or objects to show up in my generated JSON files. I have already configured my ObjectMapper accordingly using the following method:

```
objectMapper.setSerializationInclusion(Include.NON_EMPTY);
```

This works fine for arrays, collections and Strings.
However if i have an empty object (= all properties are null or empty) it will still show up in the generated JSON like this:

```
"MyObject":{}
```

Here is a possible example of what I mean with an empty object:

```
class MyClass
{
    String property1 = "";
    Object property2 = null;
}
```

In this case I want the object to be excluded completely from the generated JSON file.

Is this possible? If yes, how to I have to configure my ObjectMapper in order to get the desired behavior?

Comment: According to https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson-databind/issues/527 this feature will go to version 2.5.

Comment: Hmm I am not sure, whether this will also introduce support for objects. Additionally I think they would also have to fix this linked issue: https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson-databind/issues/588 in order to make it work for my case.

Comment: Anyways, so it seems there is currently no way to configure ObjectMapper to get the behavior I want? In that case I wonder whether there is any workaround, or an easy way to implement the functionality myself. In the worst case I will have to go and filter any empty objects out of the generated JSON file recursively until they are all gone...

Comment: I think, a workaround is to write a custom serializer for your type which does nothing if all the fields are null or empty.

Comment: What would be the purpose legitimating design for having empty objects?

Answer (score 2):

To ignore the empty values such as you may have initialized the arrayList but there are no elements in that list. In that time using NOT_EMPTY annotation to ignore those empty value fields

```
@JsonInclude(Include.NON_EMPTY)
class Foo
{
  String bar;
}
```

Answer (score -2):

It's been a few years since the question was asked, but I hit this page looking for a solution. So here it is.

You need to annotate your class with NON_DEFAULT:

```
@JsonInclude(NON_DEFAULT)
class MyClass
{
  String property1 = "";
  Object property2 = null;
}
```

Global config is not enough as explicitly stated in the documentation:
http://fasterxml.github.io/jackson-annotations/javadoc/2.7/com/fasterxml/jackson/annotation/JsonInclude.Include.html#NON_DEFAULT

The new NON_DEFAULT is available since 2.7

Comment: Did not work in my case. If the annotated object is held by a bean and serialized, it's still {"myClassObject": {}} instead of {}